# How should I free resources after using uchardet library?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, character-encoding

I use charset detector library (uchardet) in my C++ project (MS Visual Studio 2010).
I've met the following fragment of its usage in the archive:

```
void detect(FILE * fp)
{
uchardet_t handle = uchardet_new();

while (!feof(fp))
{
    size_t len = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
    int retval = uchardet_handle_data(handle, buffer, len);
    if (retval != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Handle data error.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
uchardet_data_end(handle);

const char * charset = uchardet_get_charset(handle);
if (*charset)
    printf("%s\n", charset);
else
    printf("ascii/unknown\n");

uchardet_delete(handle);
}
```

Is it OK not to call `uchardet_data_end()` and `uchardet_delete()` if `uchardet_handle_data()` returns a non-zero value? I'd like to avoid memory leaks while using this library.